# Do C compilers optimize structs with a single member?

Tags: c, struct

What does the compiler do when you  do this?

```
struct something {
    int number;
}
```

Does it differ in memory from an int?

Comment: What do you mean by "consider is as a simple int"?

Comment: @R.. Sorry for the poor choice of words. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do C compilers optimize structs with a single member?

That depends completely on the compiler. And the current compiler settings. And the code being compiled. And the platform. And the relative position of the Sirius and the Moon. We don't know. If you ask about a specific compiler, on a specific architecture, with specific compiler flags turned on, when compiling a given piece of code, we can compile it and look at the generated assembly to see what it does. But then, you could as well do that for yourself.

---

That said, generally, I'd expect a modern optimizing compiler to make this transformation when a reasonably high level of optimizations is turned on.

Edit: as to what kind of differences could there be: I am not only talking about the offset of the member inside the structs; as others have correctly observed, it is very likely that the exact same machine code is generated when accessing a member of such a structure and when operating on a stand-alone `int`.

**However,** there are other properties related to structures which can vary. I can think of two examples.

The first one is related to assignment. When you assign to a `struct`, certain compilers will emit a call to the `memcpy()` function, whereas an assignment to an `int` may only require one machine instruction without any function calls whatsoever, such as `mov [address], [value]`.

The second behavioral difference is related to function return values. Some (old) ABIs dictate that functions that return a `struct` push their return value on the stack, whereas simple primitive return values (mean built-in, core language types by that) are often placed into a register. So it is theoretically possible, for a non-optimizing compiler, to generate a `push` instruction that puts the single `int` on the stack, instead of using the return value register.

Comment: @R.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887384/do-c-compilers-optimize-structs-with-a-single-member/19887439?noredirect=1#comment29584530_19887467

Comment: @R.. But anyway, I've edited my answer to reflect what I mean more clearly.

Comment: +1 for the possible difference in the ABI for return values, wouldn't have crossed my mind.

Comment: @JensGustedt Thanks! Actually, I believe R..'s answer included that first, but I didn't realize that, so I put this in my own edit too... :D

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "optimize"? Or, more specifically, what would "non-optimized" machine code look like in this case?

The machine semantics of working to a structure containing a single `int` is the same as that of a standalone `int` variable. This means that the machine code will normally be the same regardless of whether the compiler makes any optimizations or not. I.e. such structure is already inherently the same as standalone `int` variable.

In other words, I don't understand what would you see an "non-optimized" code in this case. Where is the freedom of "non-optimizing" it?

One "non-optimization" opportunity is probably struct size alignment, which for some obscure reason might end up being greater than the size of a standalone `int`. But this does not normally happen in practice without you explicitly asking for it.

I can also imagine a compiler that would constantly attempt to add `0` to the beginning address of the structure to get to the address of the only field. But I have never seen a compiler that would do something like that in practice.

Comment: I think he didn't just consider offsets and such. This is true, for which I give you a +1, but there are other aspects to consider too. For example, some compilers implement structure assignment using `memcpy()`, but primitive `int` assignment can be done by a single `mov` instruction (let's suppose it, anyway).

Comment: @H2CO3: I would expect any decent compiler to avoid using a general-purpose memcpy for small structures, but compiler for a machine which requires integer alignment would need to distinguish between word-aligned, halfword-aligned, and unaligned 4-byte structures to regard a struct assignment as anything other than four discrete bytes.  For something like the Cortex-M0, I'd expect the four-discrete-byte case to either be four in-line load/store pairs, or else a call into a routine `Copy8: ldrb r0,[r1+7] / strb r0,[r1+7] / Copy7: ldrb r0,[r1+6] / strb r0,[r1+6] / etc.`

Comment: @supercat Emphasis is on "decent" ;-) AFAIK MSVC did use `memcpy()` for quite a long time, not sure what the current state of the art over at Microsoft is.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your new question:

> Does it differ in memory from an int?

In practice, the answer is no. An implementation is *permitted* to impose a higher alignment requirement on the structure than it would on a plain `int`, thus also expanding the *size* of the structure to match the alignment. However, there is no usefulness in doing so, and I'm not aware of any compiler that does. (Certainly the standard ABIs for all major cpu architectures and operating systems do not permit this.)

As for other aspects:

- It's possible, but unlikely, that the compiler generates less-efficient code for assignments with the structure type. As H2CO3 mentioned, it might always generate a call to `memcpy` for the structure assignment, even when a single-word load/store would do.
- One aspect nobody has touched on is argument-passing and return-values in the calling convention. It's *rare* (and generally frowned upon) to write functions that take or return structure types as arguments or return values; normally, pointers are used instead. But it is permitted in C, and whether the calling conventions for passing or returning a structure that contains a single `int` match the conventions for objects of type `int`, or use some other mechanism that generalizes to larger structures, is architecture/ABI-specific.

Comment: Um. I now see you already mentioned return values. Well, sorry for the too late and possibly confusing comment under my own answer, then.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question posits a structure containing a single `int`, structures containing a single floating-point variable are even more interesting.  Many processors have a floating-point unit (FPU) which is somewhat isolated from the rest of the CPU.  Typically, the main CPU will be able to load and store its registers from/to memory, and the FPU likewise with its registers, but there will no direct path between the main CPU's registers and those of the FPU.

Generally, when calling a function, it will be faster to pass parameters and function return values in registers than to have the caller store them in memory and have the called function read them out.  Using main-CPU registers to pass floating-point parameters and return values, however, would be just about the worst possible mechanism: if a routine like `double foo(double x) {return x*2.0}`; were invoked `y=foo(w+1.0)+3.0;`, the system would have to load `w` into an FPU register, add 1.0, store it to memory, load it into a CPU register and call `foo` which would then have to store it into memory so it could load it into the FPU.  It would then multiply by 2.0, store it back into memory, load it into a CPU register, and return, so the main code could store it into memory, load it into the FPU, add 3.0, and then finally store it to Y.  Nasty.

Performance can be much better if floating-point parameters are passed using FPU registers.  Generally, however, this will only be done with floating-point primitive types.  A struct which contains a single floating-point variable will on every system I know of be passed either using main-CPU registers or memory.  This may be a bad thing in cases where the caller and/or called code will have to perform floating-point math upon the value, but in some rare cases it may be a good thing, especially if the main CPU will have to do something with the value in question.  For example, it's possible to do a compare-and-swap operation with a 4-byte float by loading the value into a main-CPU register and having it perform the compare-and-swap, but a compare-and-swap routine which took a value in an FPU register would be somewhat slower than one which took a parameter that was either in memory or a main CPU register.  I don't know that the performance advantages would be sufficient to justify using a structure, but it may be good to be aware of them.